# Setting up explorer in mini-fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

After setting up mini fabric locally on my machine (ubuntu 18.04 LTS). I tried to start explorer. The starting process goes smoothly and the DB is up and healthy as well. But the main explorer container exits with the below error log.

```
Error: Cannot find module '/opt/explorer/main.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Any idea why this is happening. I started mini fabric with fabric 2.0.0.

Thanks a lot for you're support.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a  problem with the new explorer image. Grab the latest minifab from [official minifabric repo](https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/minifabric) and the issue will be fixed.

To update your minifabric to the latest version, please refer to [Docs](https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/minifabric/blob/master/docs/README.md#update-minifabric).

Also it is a good idea to keep your minifabric updated once in a while, as it is a fast moving project.

Comment: Oh I am sorry forgot to update it here. We already fixed the issue 
https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/minifabric/issues/89